# Как ограничить действия пользователя на сайте?

Tags: python, django

как ограничить действия конкретного авторизованного пользователя на сайте?
Например, если он уже отредактировал свой профиль, то в течении суток он больше не сможет это сделать.
Что почитать или какой код использовать?
Очень удобно было б это сделать в админ панельке Django, чтобы только админ мог вводить ограничения на каждого индивидуального пользователя.